# Send PDF to printer for printing using SSIS

Tags: pdf, printing, ssis

I am trying to accomplish the task: printing PDF files at printer via SSIS silently.
I have tried different ways,

1. Execute Process Task + PDFtoPrinter: It works on my local machine, printouts available. On server, the job runs successfully, but no printout.
2. Execute Process Task + Adobe reader: It works on my local machine, but it opens GUI
3. Script Task + PDFtoPrinter: It works on my local machine, printouts available. On server, similar to solution 1, the job runs successfully, but no printout.

In general, I prefer using PDFtoPrinter.exe, but there is very limited log. I suspected, could it be it needs some wait time, so I put in some waits(30000), still did not solve the problem. Could it be possibly permission related? Having said that I am sure the exe and file folder are reachable.

I also tried to turn on SSIS log and it did not return any valuable insights. Any help is appreciated.

#Fields: event,computer,operator,source,sourceid,executionid,starttime,endtime,datacode,databytes,message
User:ExecuteProcessVariableRouting,xxx,xxx,Print pdf,{xxx},{xxx},06.12.2021 14:06:18,06.12.2021 14:06:18,0,,Routing stdout from variable "User::OutputFromPrinting"
User:ExecuteProcessVariableRouting,xxx,xxx,Print pdf,{xxx},{xxx},06.12.2021 14:06:18,06.12.2021 14:06:18,0,,Routing stderr from variable "User::ErrorFromPrinting"
User:ExecuteProcessExecutingProcess,xxx,xxx,Print pdf,{xxx},{xxx},06.12.2021 14:06:18,06.12.2021 14:06:18,0,,Executing the process "\xxx\PDFtoPrinter.exe" with the arguments ""\xxx\sample.pdf" "Printer1" /s ".
User:ExecuteProcessExecutingProcess,xxx,xxx,Print pdf,{xxx},{xxx},06.12.2021 14:06:34,06.12.2021 14:06:34,0,,Process has exited

Comment: Unlikely I will be able to install additional program on server. Can you perhaps shed some light on the ghost script? Is Ghostscript also something like PDFtoPrinter, where I can just execute on command line and print to specific printer?

Comment: But with ghostscript, my understanding is it requires an installation. Whereas, pdftoprinter, you can use it without installation. Do you know could it be any type of permission issue involved?

Comment: So after some more testing, it looks like the package executes successfully on server and papers are printed, when we manually executes SSIS on server. However, if we have the agent job with proxy to execute the package. The package executes successfully, but no printouts.